# How do I make a date format for an entire column in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe-

```
df1
Out[12]: 
       DateTime ClaimStatus  NumberOfClaims
0     8/12/2016      Queued            5301
1     8/13/2016      Queued            5419
2     8/14/2016      Queued            5369
3     8/15/2016      Queued            5015
4     8/16/2016      Queued            5081
```

I want to make the DateTime column format into YYY-MM-DD
I know how to make it individually -

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.strptime("1/4/2014", "%m/%d/%Y")    
datetime.strftime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

How do I apply this to the DateTime column in df1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following if you want to keep the column as datetime format:

```
df1['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DateTime'], format="%m/%d/%Y")
```